# How to use single sign on

Tags: facebook, appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app using Appcelerator. I need to use Facebook and if the user has the facebook app installed they are taken there to authorize my app and then back to the app again. The problem is that after the user has been redirected to the Facebook app and authorizes my app there they are not returned back to my app automatically. Why is that?

I use:

```
Titanium.Facebook.forceDialogAuth = false;
```

I also need to use the in app popup window if the Facebook app is not installed.

What can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I read through the Appcelerator Q&A and I got my answer [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/137876/how-to-use-facebook-single-sign-on)

The accepted answer talked about adding this line to tiapp.xml below guid:

```
<property name="ti.facebook.appid">134793934930</property>
```

and if you have a info.plist, then add this right after CFBundleURLTypes:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.appcelerator.titanium</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>kitchensink</string>
            <string>fb134793934930</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Don't just post a link - explain the content and how it helps.

Comment: Kevin, I made an edit (assuming accepted) that gives one example of what you could do when including links.